# insert white gaussian nois in images using python

Tags: python, matlab, gaussian

I tried to search python function which corresponding to the Matlab function(imnoise). I want to Augment the images using the white Gaussian noise.

Tha matlab code for white Gaussian noise::

```
[I, map]=imread("img.png");
I=double(I)/255;
V=var(I(:)); %compute the image variance
J=imnoise(I, 'gaussian', 0, V/10); %insert gaussian white noise with mean zero and tenth of that variance
```

Comment: What have you tried in Python?

Comment: from skimage.util import random_noise

Comment: so what's the problem/ question?

Comment: Was that all you tried? ... Did it work? Did you get any errors?

Comment: Thx all, I think that I wast have little mistake and misunderstanding. It solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use numpy and Pillow for that!

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Load the image into a numpy array
I = Image.open(filename)
I_array = np.array(im)

# Calculate the variance for the image and the noise
M = 0
V = np.var(im_array)
noise = np.random.normal(mean, variance, I_array.shape)

# Add the noise to the image numpy array and convert
# everything back to a PIL image.
I_array_noise = np.add(I_array, noise)
J = Image.fromarray(I_array_noise)
```